# Working out how thick a stack of 80GB of printed A4 papers will be

Tags: arithmetic, word-problem

I been going through some of my math unit workbook for Computer Science and im stuck on a question which is phrased:

"Given that a single page of A4 paper can display 50 rows by 60 columns of 12pt text, each character takes 1 byte of storage and 1 ream (500 sheets) of 80 gsm paper is 5cm thick, how many meters of shelving are required to store 80GB of information that has been printed on a single sided paper?"

the answer is 2863.31 meters but im not sure how the answers is worked out, could anyone spare a a minute to go through the steps with me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried breaking it down into its components? Figure out how much data fits on one page, then find out how many of those pages makes 80 GB. Lastly figure out how many reams are made from that many pieces of paper.

Comment: And once you do what jaska said, note the goofy-looking 2863.31. I did it to get 2666.67, which looked more reasonable, and then I realized $1K=1024$, not $1K=1000$. And to get your answer, you have to use $1G=(1024)^3$.

Comment: Good catch @JohnForkosh

Comment: I think i understand now thank you guys, i just realised how much work i need to do on my math skills over this summer

Comment: Math is more important for CS than many students like to believe

Comment: @jaska yea I've just realised how important it is, I've tended to shy away from the subject cause im not very good at it but now I must face my fears

Comment: By the way, google "library of congress terabytes" and get various estimates between $\sim10-74\mbox{TB}$ for the size of its print (emphasize **print**) collection, though various comments suggest that's lowballing it. So, just for fun, let's simply say $80\mbox{TB}$ and let's say $3000\mbox{meters/80GB}$. That works out to (you guessed it) $3000\mbox{km}$ of shelf space containing print material in the library of congress. And https://www.loc.gov/about/fascinating-facts/ says $838\mbox{miles}$ of shelves. Close enough! So that was fun...unless you're the one who has to dust those shelves.

Answer (score 1):

1. How many bytes per sheet?
2. How many sheets per centimetre?
3. Therefore, how many bytes per centimetre?
4. And how many bytes per metre? Call this number $N$.

Now the answer is just $(80\times 2^{30}/N)$ metres. (This assumes that a gigabyte is defined as $2^{30}$ bytes, which agrees with your stated answer.)